# Consider the sequence of rational numbers $\{a_k\}_k\geq1$ where $q_k=\sum^k_{n=1} \frac{1}{10^{n^2}}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Consider the sequence of rational numbers $\{a_k\}_k\geq1$ where $q_k=\sum^k_{n=1} \frac{1}{10^{n^2}}$  i.e, the sequence is $q_1=0.1, q_2=0.1001,q_3=0.100100001$, then this sequence is bounded and Cauchy but not convergent sequence

Since this sequence having a non-terminating decimal expansion so not convergent in Q .then how to prove this sequence is bounded and cauchy

Comment: @user1... i edited my post

Comment: 'non-terminating decimal expansion' isn't enough to show that it doesn't converge in $\mathbb{Q}$; consider $\frac13=0.\bar{3}$.  Even 'non-periodic decimal expansion' probably won't be enough to satisfy most professors, since you don't even have access to $\sum_{n=1}^\infty 10^{-n^2}$; you should be able to prove the theorem using only properties of $\mathbb{Q}$ itself.

Comment: Instead, try and get at the _essence_ of what having a non-periodic decimal expansion means here - you should be able to show directly that it can't be $\frac pq$ for any $p,q$.  As for the rest - a bound in $\mathbb{Q}$ should be nearly trivial to show (hint: $\sum_n 10^{-n^2}\lt\sum_n 10^{-n}$) and Cauchyness is just as trivial.